# How do i display filetype icons as nodes in vis.js?

Tags: vis.js

I know how to display images, but my intention is to display icons such as pdf, xlsx, pptx, docx, csv, etc..  I want to be able to extract the file extension from a filename (which I know how to do and discussed in a previous post), but when I get the extension, I want to display as a node for the document its unique icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/):

```
  var nodes = [{
    id: 5,
    label: 'File 5.pdf',
    shape: 'icon',
    icon: {
      face: 'FontAwesome',
      code: "\uf1c1",
      size: 50,
      color: '#f0a30a'
    }
  }];
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/wsphzt96/ ]